# PyTorch Model Training: RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, reinforcement-learning, dqn

After training a PyTorch model on a GPU for several hours, the program fails with the error

> RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

**Training Conditions**

- Neural Network: PyTorch 4-layer `nn.LSTM` with `nn.Linear` output
- Deep Q Network Agent (Vanilla DQN with Replay Memory)
- `state` passed into `forward()` has the shape `(32, 20, 15)`, where `32` is the batch size
- 50 seconds per episode
- Error occurs after about 583 episodes (8 hours) or 1,150,000 steps, where each step involves a forward pass through the LSTM model.

My code also has the following values set before the training began

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
np.random.seed(0)
```

How can we troubleshoot this problem? Since this occurred 8 hours into the training, some educated guess will be very helpful here!

Thanks!

---

**Update:**

Commenting out the 2 `torch.backends.cudnn...` lines did not work. `CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR` still occurs, but much earlier at around Episode 300 (585,000 steps).

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
#torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
#torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
np.random.seed(0)
```

---

**System**

- PyTorch 1.6.0.dev20200525
- CUDA 10.2
- cuDNN 7604
- Python 3.8
- Windows 10
- nVidia 1080 GPU

**Error Traceback**

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-f5bbb4fdfda5> in <module>
     57 
     58     while not done:
---> 59         action = agent.choose_action(state)
     60         state_, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
     61         score += reward

<ipython-input-11-5ad4dd57b5ad> in choose_action(self, state)
     58         if np.random.random() > self.epsilon:
     59             state = T.tensor([state], dtype=T.float).to(self.q_eval.device)
---> 60             actions = self.q_eval.forward(state)
     61             action = T.argmax(actions).item()
     62         else:

<ipython-input-10-94271a92f66e> in forward(self, state)
     20 
     21     def forward(self, state):
---> 22         lstm, hidden = self.lstm(state)
     23         actions = self.fc1(lstm[:,-1:].squeeze(1))
     24         return actions

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\rl\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    575             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    576         else:
--> 577             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    578         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    579             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\rl\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
    571         self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
    572         if batch_sizes is None:
--> 573             result = _VF.lstm(input, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, self.num_layers,
    574                               self.dropout, self.training, self.bidirectional, self.batch_first)
    575         else:

RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Update: Tried `try... except` on my code where this error occurs at, and in addition to `RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR`, we also get a second traceback for the error `RuntimeError: CUDA error: unspecified launch failure`

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e8f15cc8cf4f> in <module>
     61 
     62     while not done:
---> 63         action = agent.choose_action(state)
     64         state_, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
     65         score += reward

<ipython-input-3-1aae79080e99> in choose_action(self, state)
     58         if np.random.random() > self.epsilon:
     59             state = T.tensor([state], dtype=T.float).to(self.q_eval.device)
---> 60             actions = self.q_eval.forward(state)
     61             action = T.argmax(actions).item()
     62         else:

<ipython-input-2-6d22bb632c4c> in forward(self, state)
     25         except Exception as e:
     26             print('error in forward() with state:', state.shape, 'exception:', e)
---> 27             print('state:', state)
     28         actions = self.fc1(lstm[:,-1:].squeeze(1))
     29         return actions

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\rl\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in __repr__(self)
    152     def __repr__(self):
    153         # All strings are unicode in Python 3.
--> 154         return torch._tensor_str._str(self)
    155 
    156     def backward(self, gradient=None, retain_graph=None, create_graph=False):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\rl\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor_str.py in _str(self)
    331                 tensor_str = _tensor_str(self.to_dense(), indent)
    332             else:
--> 333                 tensor_str = _tensor_str(self, indent)
    334 
    335     if self.layout != torch.strided:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\rl\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor_str.py in _tensor_str(self, indent)
    227     if self.dtype is torch.float16 or self.dtype is torch.bfloat16:
    228         self = self.float()
--> 229     formatter = _Formatter(get_summarized_data(self) if summarize else self)
    230     return _tensor_str_with_formatter(self, indent, formatter, summarize)
    231 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\rl\lib\site-packages\torch\_tensor_str.py in __init__(self, tensor)
     99 
    100         else:
--> 101             nonzero_finite_vals = torch.masked_select(tensor_view, torch.isfinite(tensor_view) & tensor_view.ne(0))
    102 
    103             if nonzero_finite_vals.numel() == 0:

RuntimeError: CUDA error: unspecified launch failure
```

Comment: In my case the error was labels. Model outputs 53 values dataset was outputting labels starting from 0 but the cross-entropy was expecting the labels starting from 0. So, changing this fixed my issue.

Comment: My problem was actually caused by out-of-memory, but I am not sure why this error comes out instead.

Answer (score 31):

The error `RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR` is notoriously difficult to debug, but surprisingly often it's an out of memory problem. Usually, you would get the out of memory error, but depending on where it occurs, PyTorch cannot intercept the error and therefore not provide a meaningful error message.

A memory issue seems to be likely in your case, because you are using a while loop until the agent is done, which might take long enough that you run out of memory, it's just a matter of time. That can also possibly occur rather late, once the model's parameters in combination with a certain input is unable to finish in time.

You can avoid that scenario by limiting the number of allowed actions instead of hoping that the actor will be done in a reasonable time.

What you also need to be careful about, is that you don't occupy unnecessary memory. A common mistake is to keep computing gradients of the past states in future iterations. The state from the last iteration should be considered constant, since the current action should not affect past actions, therefore no gradients are required. This is usually achieved by detaching the state from the computational graph for the next iteration, e.g. `state = state_.detach()`. Maybe you are already doing that, but without the code it's impossible to tell.

Similarly, if you keep a history of the states, you should detach them and even more importantly put them on the CPU, i.e. `history.append(state.detach().cpu())`.

Comment: Should I interpret this as "Python CUDA libraries are not smart enough to automatically handle memory management and you're running you of GPU RAM because of a memory leak in your program"?

Answer (score 9):

Anyone coming across this error as well as other cudnn/gpu related errors should try to change the model and inputs to cpu, generally the cpu runtime has much better error reporting and will enable you to debug the issue.

In my experience majority of the time the error comes from invalid index on an embedding.

Comment: I never thought this would work, but I actually got it working with this.. apparently I have some wonky cuda installation

Comment: That is exactly what I met most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Reducing num_workers worked for me :D

Comment: This is more of a comment, than an answer. At 50+ reputation, you may post comments. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and resolved it by downgrading cudatoolkit to version 10.1. So try to reinstall pytorch with cudatoolkit 10.1.

```sh
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1
```

Comment: Did you to this in your own machine, or in Google Colab?

Answer (score 1):

I think reduce batch-size and it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because there are two processes from the previous run that somehow weren't killed properly, and they occupied two GPUs, causing the same cudnn error.

The error disappears after killing these two processes

Comment: `pkill python3` - use this to kill stray processes on linux

Answer (score 1):

Personally I consider this problem relates to GPU memory allocation.  My  workaround solution is kind of ... alternative, but it works for me most of the time.  I'm working on an Ubuntu 22.04LTS workstation and from time to time either this problem occurs or "torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory" comes.  Either problem persists no matter if my program do "gc.collect()" or "torch.cuda.empty_cache()".

However, whenever I have these problems I only have to use my 'TeamViewer' (currently version 15.45.3, installed on my Ubuntu workstation) to connect to another machine, operated a few seconds then disconnect it, quit my TeamViewer.  Magically my program will work again and usually kept working for a long time.  Sometimes merely quit my browser (which usually utilize GPU) also works.

The logic behind it I believe is because TeamViewer will itself causing GPU memory allocation and deallocation which eventually make the GPU memory condition changes and eventually bypassed the unknown root problem that considers difficult to debug as [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073916/3818556) indicated.  My guess is that other programs that use GPU might also help but I didn't spend time checking so if anyone found other workarounds or please kindly provide.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I had another process running.  After killing it, this worked.  I know I was right about at my memory limit too because I had to reduce parameters to avoid the out of memory error.  Then this popped up.  Released extra memory and it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for everyone as there could be other factors like workers, installed Cuda version and more.

For me, a system restart fixed it on my Windows 11 machine with an Nvidia Geforce RTX3070 with 8GB memory. My machine had been on for days with many programs getting in and out of the GPU.